# How to get autocomplete for :set?

Tags: command-line, autocompletion, set

E.g. I am trying to change [`foldmethod`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27foldmethod%27) to `syntax`:

```
:set foldmethod=s^I^I
```

When I press <kbd>tab</kbd> after typing `s`, I get `^I` instead of auto-completing to `syntax`. Only possible options are `manual`,`indent`,`expr`,`marker`,`syntax`,`diff`. So it should be possible to get auto-completion.

Comment: This isn't implemented unfortunately, so you can't do this; not without sending a patch to Vim anyway. I think I should still have a patch to add completion for many of the options with a static list of values, but I haven't really gotten around to finishing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was recently implemented. Just update to Vim 9.0.1958 and it will just work.

[Relevant commit](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/900894b09a95398dfc75599e9f0aa2ea25723384):

> ```
> patch 9.0.1958: cannot complete option values
> Problem:  cannot complete option values
> Solution: Add completion functions for several options
>
> Add cmdline tab-completion for setting string options
>
> Add tab-completion for setting string options on the cmdline using
> `:set=` (along with `:set+=` and `:set-=`).
>
> The existing tab completion for setting options currently only works
> when nothing is typed yet, and it only fills in with the existing value,
> e.g. when the user does `:set diffopt=<Tab>` it will be completed to
> `set diffopt=internal,filler,closeoff` and nothing else. This isn't too
> useful as a user usually wants auto-complete to suggest all the possible
> values, such as 'iblank', or 'algorithm:patience'.
>
> For set= and set+=, this adds a new optional callback function for each
> option that can be invoked when doing completion. This allows for each
> option to have control over how completion works. For example, in
> 'diffopt', it will suggest the default enumeration, but if `algorithm:`
> is selected, it will further suggest different algorithm types like
> 'meyers' and 'patience'. When using set=, the existing option value will
> be filled in as the first choice to preserve the existing behavior. When
> using set+= this won't happen as it doesn't make sense.
>
> For flag list options (e.g. 'mouse' and 'guioptions'), completion will
> take into account existing typed values (and in the case of set+=, the
> existing option value) to make sure it doesn't suggest duplicates.
>
> For set-=, there is a new `ExpandSettingSubtract` function which will
> handle flag list and comma-separated options smartly, by only suggesting
> values that currently exist in the option.
>
> Note that Vim has some existing code that adds special handling for
> 'filetype', 'syntax', and misc dir options like 'backupdir'. This change
> preserves them as they already work, instead of converting to the new
> callback API for each option.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for creating the Patch! Relevant Vim commit: https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/900894b09a95398dfc75599e9f0aa2ea25723384

Comment: Great! Thank you!